# Suppose $f$ is a measurable function and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$. Prove that g is a measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions

Suppose $f$ is a measurable function and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$. Prove that g is a measurable function.

Using the definition of a measurable function I have,

$\{x : f(x) > a\} \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can I rewrite $\{x : f(x) > a\} = \{x : \frac{1}{f(x)} < \frac{1}{a} \} = \{x : g(x) < b, \frac{1}{a} = b\}$

Comment: What makes you think that you *can't* write what you have written?

Comment: I'm worried making the change to the reciprocal would be removing some values of $x$.

Comment: Is your function target the reals or extended reals?

Comment: You forgot to flip the inequality when taking reciprocals. Otherwise, you are essentially done.  If you want to convince yourself further, you can run the argument backwards and say "fix $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\{x : g(x)>b\} = ... \in \mathcal{A}$.  [edited comment: It looks like the existing answer that I just read does just this].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show that a function is measurable, it is necessary to show that the preimage of each measurable set is measurable.  To do this, it is sufficient to show that the preimage of each interval of the form $(b,\infty)$ is measurable.  So, suppose that $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have
\begin{align}
g^{-1}((b,\infty))
&= \left\{ x : g(x) > b\right\} \\
&= \left\{ x : \frac{1}{f(x)} > b \right\} \\
&= \left\{ x : \frac{1}{b} > f(x) \right\} \\
&= f^{-1}\left( \left(-\infty, \frac{1}{b} \right)\right). \tag{$\ast$}
\end{align}
Since $f$ is a measurable function, the preimage of every open set is measurable, which implies that the set at ($\ast$) is measurable.  But this is what we needed to show, therefore $g = \frac{1}{f}$ is measurable.

Note that if we allow the range of $g$ to include $\pm\infty$ (i.e. if we work in the extended real numbers), this proof works perfectly well (with only slight modification) when we allow $f$ to take nonpositive values.  Thus the hypothesis that $f(x) > 0$ is not strictly necessary, though we do have to enlarge the codomain to make sense of the argument.

Comment: This makes plenty of sense. Aside from the fact it was incomplete thought. Is there anything you dislike about my approach. It seems very similar to your response, but you came from the other direction.

Comment: When proving a statement, I like to keep the end result in mind.  To show that $g$ is (Borel) measurable, I need to show that the preimage of **any** open set is measurable (since the open sets generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra).  To do this, it is sufficient to show that the preimage of every interval (of whatever specific form I require) is measurable, since intervals generate the same $\sigma$-algebra.  Thus I start with an arbitrary interval, and work from there.  Your approach can be made to work, but feels backwards to me.